# Windows XP Win32 API to detect add/removal of audio devices?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, win64

Getting a notification of a device add/remove in Vista+ is trivial, but I can't seem to find an API that works with Windows XP that allows me to get a notification when an audio device is added or removed.  The best solution I've been able to come up with is to poll mixerGetDevCaps and look for changes, but this doesn't seem to be ideal.

What is the best Win32 API to use to detect added or removed audio devices that works with Windows XP SP2+?

Comment: [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IInspectable's hint let me to WM_DEVICECHANGE window notification, which is the answer I was looking for.  This does require a window to work which while not ideal, is sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: That's what [Message-Only Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) are for.

Comment: Alternatively, a service can use `RegisterDeviceNotification()` to ask for `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT` notifications, which carry most of the same information that `WM_DEVICECHANGED` provides, but without needing a window to receive it.